# Sorting and filtering JSON documents stored in Redis

Tags: json, mongodb, clojure, redis

I am thinking about substituting MongoDB with Redis for a very frequently updated JSON data store (~50000 upd/sec). It can contain up to a million of records.

Data store clients are now using MongoDB's query language to enable result sorting/filtering. Result sets might include dozens of thousands of records. After filtering only specific subsections of stored JSONs might be returned.

What features does Redis provide to simplify the conversion task? Will i necessarily have to implementing the sorting/filtering in the application code itself (we will use Java/Clojure)?

Answer (score -1):

Redis is a key-value database.

> Redis is an open source, BSD licensed, advanced key-value cache and store. It is often referred to as a data structure server since keys can contain strings, hashes, lists, sets, sorted sets, bitmaps and hyperloglogs.

Do you think is a god idea to manage users with more than one column in mongodb?

You can use Redis to manage users like: User ID - other column
With Redis you can return list ordered by value, first ten users... to get it and manage nodeJS with [REDIS NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) and then get all json data ordered in my app.

Comment: And yet the question itself mentions clojure and not node.js